# WiFi (SSID) name not showing after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have Windows 7 Home Premium laptop.

Using *MediaCreationTool21H1*, I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10 and upgrade was done successfully.

After upgrade, I see all nearby available wifi but I don’t see wifi name with which it was connected when it was Windows 7.

I disabled and enabled wifi from Network Connection, added wireless network manually and uninstalled wireless driver from device manager.

However, same issue, my wifi name (SSID name) is not showing in the list and no internet.

At the end, I rolled back to Windows 7. In Windows 7, it is connected to the wifi automatically with which it was connected earlier.

Please let me know, what I need to do so that I can resolve it.

With Regards
InTech

Comment: You might need to upgrade the firmware on your router. As old as Windows 7? Possibly even a new router is in order.

Comment: Your Win7 has connected to the same SSID before, so it'd connect there automatically whether or not the SSID is visible. Is it visible on Win7?

Comment: WiFi networks can get hidden if they are running on a non-global channel and the OS thinks you are in a country where this channel is not allowed. In any way a clean Win10 installation is recommended then you should not face such problems.